# PHP PDO insert with arrays

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

I am having an issue inserting data into my database using PDO as the wrong results are being input.

the class works as follows:

```
class PDOMySql{
public function connect(){
            try{
                $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->server.';dbname='.$this->database,$this->username,$this->password);
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
                if(!$dbh){
                    throw new Exception('Error Connecting to Server');
                }
                return $dbh;

            }   catch(Exception $e){
                    if(MAILING == "ON"){
                        $this->report->mailing($e);
                    }
                    else{
                        throw $e;
                    }
            }
        }

public function insert($query,$values,$dbh){
        try{
            if(!is_array($values)){
                throw new Exception("Values must be in array format: e.g: array('a','b','c')");
            }
            $a = substr_count($query,'?');
            $b = count($values);
            if($a != $b){
                throw new Exception("Number of values must match the number of placements");
            }
            $prepare = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $i = 1;
            foreach($values as $item){
                $type = strtolower(gettype($item));
                if($type == "null"){
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                }
                elseif($type == "string"){
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
                elseif($type == "integer"){
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("Type: PDO::PARAM_".$type. " Not currently supported");
                }
                    $prepare->bindParam($i, $item, $param);
                $i++;
            }

            $prepare->execute();
            $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();             
            return $lastId;

        }   catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }

    }

}
```

When the class is called like this:

```
$db = new MySql(); $con = $db->connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (a,b,c,d) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$values = array("1st column", "2nd column",null,"asdfasd");
$a = $db->insert($sql,$values,$con);
```

the values inserted are as follows:
a : 1st Column. 
b : 2nd Column. 
c : 2nd Column. 
d : asdfasd.

as you can see instead of inputting null the second value is put into the c column.

Is there an easier way to insert dynamically created values as some maybe null and using this method above it seems to ignore null and use the last value. Does anyone know why this is happening or if there is an easier method to do so?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. please check with the PHP bugtracker if there is a known problem with your PHP and PDO version.

Comment: What if instead of passing `null`, you pass the string `'null'`.

Comment: tried it and edited this to add it but someone edited it and deleted the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use bindValue() instead of bindParam().

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

```
$prepare->bindValue($i, $item, $param);
```

However, it's considered bad practice to have so many anonymous values `(?,?,?,?)` ... You should be using placeholders, if they are going from a $_POST array, you can foreach the $_POST array and use the keys as placeholders

Comment: I have changed the code the use an array with a key and changed my foreach to foreach($value as $key => $item) then used bindValue(':'.$key.', $item, PDO::PARAM_STR);